# Fade in and fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make the div with all of the images fade in and fade out at once?
The div with the images should at first be hidden, then fade in after clicking some button then fade out.

https://jsfiddle.net/f8juy5pb/3/

```
<div id="a">
<img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image10"src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
</div>


#a img { 
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 6%;
    height: 75px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;

}


#a:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)/[fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) with [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) to detect if the images are current display or not

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  if ($('img:visible').length) {
    $('img').fadeOut();
  } else {
    $('img').fadeIn();
  }

});
```

```css
#a img {

  float: left;

  width: 15%;

  margin-right: 5%;

  margin-bottom: 6%;

  height: 75px;

  max-width: 100%;

  max-height: 100%;

}

#a:after {

  clear: both;

  content: "";

  display: table;

}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
<button>fade</button>
```

Comment: i have this fade in/out code..
     <script>
    function myFunction() {
    $("#second").fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $("#a").fadeIn(6000);
    });
}
</script>

<script>
   function myFunction2() {
    $("#a").fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $("#second").fadeIn(6000);
    });
}
</script>

Comment: however when i open my site, i see div: a appearing and not hidden to be triggered by a button .. Any idea why>?

Comment: @randy, can you replicate what you are trying to do with that code in a fiddle?

Comment: yeah sure, give me a sec

Comment: @randy, you provided an incomplete fiddle with undefined objects and non-existing functions `checklist`. Can you get it to where everything is working except the fading?

Comment: @randy can you explain briefly what you expecting?

Comment: @Sathish can we open a chat conv?